# Angular Typescript - using a custom filter inside a controller

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have a custom filter in my angular application (typescript) as below:

```
namespace InterACT {
  export namespace Filters {
    export class ContractAppliedTo {
      public static onFilterApplied(contract: Interfaces.IReimbursementContract) {
        if (contract.services && contract.services.length > 0) {
          return _.map(contract.services, 'regNumber').join(', ');
        } else if (contract.operator) {
          return contract.operator.name;
        }
        return contract.scheme.abbreviation;
      }
    }
  }
}

angular
  .module('app.settlement')
  .filter('contractAppliedTo', () => { return InterACT.Filters.ContractAppliedTo.onFilterApplied; });
```

I am able to use this filter just fine in my markup like other built in filters:

```
{{rule | contractAppliedTo}}
```

I now need to use this filter in a controller, and am struggling how to reference it for usage.

I already use angular date filters in some of my controllers, and in the constructor of these, I am injecting in ng.IFilterService and assigning to a private variable for usage later on.

```
namespace InterACT {
  export namespace Controllers {
    export class MyController {

      public static $inject = ['$filter'];
      constructor(
        private $filter: ng.IFilterService
            ) {
            }

            public someFunction = () => {
                let dateFilter = this.$filter('date'),
                    foo;

                foo = dateFilter('some-date-string', 'd-M-Y');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When it comes to using my ContractAppliedTo filter, I can't get the controller to recognise it for me to use, or I guess what I mean is the typescript compiler wont pick it up.

I wondered if I could use the filter service to grab an instance of my new filter, e.g:

```
let contractAppliedTo = this.$filter('contractAppliedTo')
```

But when I try to use it, I get a typescript error saying

```
[ts] Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type '{}' has no compatible call signatures.
```

I think I am missing an interface in order to be able to use this filter in my controller.

Can someone advise further please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This issue is that the `FilterService` cannot find the call signature for your custom filter. I was able to get around the issue by importing the custom filter and using `type assertion` against the usage of the `$filter` service.

```
const contractAppliedTo: contractAppliedTo = 
      (<contractAppliedTo>this.$filter('contractAppliedTo'));
```